# Hive meta exception while running hive script through oozie workflow which has drop statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, oozie

I am facing the issue of hive meta exception when we ran the hive script with oozie workflow.

I am facing this issue only when I have drop statement in the hive script and this is not happening every time only some times I experience the issue.

So some one help me to fix the issue.

Comment: please post exact exception.

Comment: This is the exception i am getting Message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
[main] ERROR hive.ql.exec.DDLTask  - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException) Please let me know if need any info.